# Как запретить выводить комментарии в коде html-страницы?

Tags: html, jsp

Доброго времени суток.

Как я могу запретить выводить комментарии в HTML-коде? Иными словами, мне надо закоментировать свой `html/jsp` код, но нельзя, чтобы  мой комментарий можно было увидеть в `html`-коде, выводимом у клиента на странице.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте ставить комментарии вне тегов html, например в рхр.

```
<Здесь html разметка>
<?php //Ваш комментарий ?>
</Опять html разметка>
```

Comment: А вот это свежая идея!  Дополню: для  jsp будет так:    
`<% //sdfsdf %>`  
 
Спасибо.

Comment: @Антон Мухин, тогда уже 
<%-- комментарий --%> 
для jsp.